# Making epub, pdf, mobi formats available in a post?

Tags: media, media-library, pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to upload and allow downloads of .mobi and .epub formats](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42669/how-to-upload-and-allow-downloads-of-mobi-and-epub-formats)

I am considering the feasibility of converting a client site from a large number of hand-built web pages to a WordPress installation. Many of the articles contain links to the PDF, mobi, and epub versions of the article. They are direct links which trigger a download. Are there any plugins which might make this process easier to manage long term and easier as I convert the content over to WordPress?

It seems like I ought to be able to create libraries with the media manager and drag-and-drop the links into the post/page. Any recommendations? Thank you!

A related question posted here [how to upload and allow downloads of .mobi and .epub formats](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42669/how-to-upload-and-allow-downloads-of-mobi-and-epub-formats) gives a partial answer. Definitely something to explore.

Comment: What is the actual question here? The link you posted tells you exactly how to add support to the media uploader, then you just click a button to insert it as a link, like usual.

Comment: It's that simple? I was overthinking it. Thank you!